# Soundcloud API ReferenceError: $ is not defined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, soundcloud

I had posted a question yesterday and thought I had fixed it on my own, but I guess I didn't. I am trying to use the SoundCloud API and I am getting an error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined.
I thought it may be due to loading jquery.js but it doesn't seem to make any difference.
Heres my code(Javascript)

```
    SC.initialize({
       client_id: 'hidden for privacy',
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        SC.get('/users/5577686/tracks', {limit:7}, function(tracks) {
        $(tracks).each(function(index, track) {
        $('#tracktitle').append($('<li></li>').html(track.title));
        $('#trackimage').append("<img src='" + track.artwork_url + "' />");
        $('#play').append("<a href='" + track.permalink_url + "' >" + "Play" + "</a>");
    });
  });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
    <script src="//jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
    <script src="soundcloud2.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="tracktitle"></div>
        <div id="trackimage"></div>
        <div id="play"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading

Comment: that path to jquery can't possibly be right. Look at your network tab, or even the resources tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using your local file system? If so, you won't be able to use a protocol relative URL.

You'll need to specify http. Try:

```
<script src="http://jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cdn URL is wrong

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Also if your pages is loaded from local file system(ie with protocol `file:`) this will not work, in that case you need to append the protocol to the resource url like `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js`